# Using the characteristic of exhaustive for probabilities

Tags: statistics

Let $F$ and $G$ be events in the same sample space with $P(F)=0.67$ and $P(G)=0.55$. If it is known that $F$ and $G$ are exhaustive, what is $P(F \cap G)$? I know the answer is $0.22$ but I don't know how they were able to get that, I don't know how the characteristic of exhaustive affects the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

I guess that $F$ and $G$ are exhaustive means that $P(F \cup G) = 1$. In that case you have
$$1 = P(F \cup G) = P(F) + P(G) - P(F \cap G) = 0.67 + 0.55 - P(F \cap G) = 1.22 - P(F\cap G).$$
Hence,
$$P(F \cap G) = 0.22.$$